# How can I convert all DateTime properties to a different TimeZone in a collection?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datetime, timezone

I have a site that has users, and I have an API method to display a user's latest activity:

```
public List<UserActivity> GetUserActivity(Guid userId)
{
    return _dbContext.UserActivity
               .Where(ua => ua.UserId.Equals(userId))
               .OrderByDescending(ua => ua.ActivityTime)
               .Take(20)
               .ToList();
}
```

These are the objects I'm returning:

```
public class UserActivity
{        
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime ActivityTime { get; set; }
    public string ActivityTitle { get; set; }
}
```

I'm storing all my dates for `ActivityTime` in UTC in my database. Each user can set which timezone they're in, so I'd like to return the `ActivityTime` converted to their timezone for display on the frontend when this API method is called.

Something like this:

```
public List<UserActivity> GetUserActivity(Guid userId)
{
    MyUser user = _dbContext.MyUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(userId));
    TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(user.TimeZoneId);

    return _dbContext.UserActivity
               .Where(ua => ua.UserId.Equals(userId))
               .OrderByDescending(ua => ua.ActivityTime)
               .Take(20)
               // somehow call TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc on ActivityTime here
               .ToList();
}
```

But I'm not sure how to call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` on a property in a collection to convert all of them. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Storing them in UTC is definitely a good start. As for Converting them to fit the timezone the user selected, this toutorial seems to be decent: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/Feb/10/Back-to-Basics-UTC-and-TimeZones-in-NET-Web-Apps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have all your `UserActivity` data in memory, then you can convert it.

```
var activities = ...;
TimeZoneInfo userZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(user.TimeZoneId);
foreach (var thisActivity in activities)
{
    DateTime localTime = 
       TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(thisActivity.ActivityTime, userZone);
    thisActivity.ActivityTime = localTime;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The important thing you need to do is to convert your DateTime entities *after* calling `ToList()` for your EntityFramework DbSet.

Here is an example using just LINQ by projecting your entities:

```
public List<UserActivity> GetUserActivity(Guid userId)
{
    MyUser user = _dbContext.MyUsers.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id.Equals(userId));
    TimeZoneInfo userTimeZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(user.TimeZoneId);

    var activities = _dbContext.UserActivity
                               .Where(ua => ua.UserId.Equals(userId))
                               .OrderByDescending(ua => ua.ActivityTime)
                               .Take(20)
                               .ToList();

    return activities.Select(a => new UserActivity
    {
        UserId = a.Userid,
        ActivityTitle = a.ActivityTitle,
        ActivityTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(a.ActivityTime, userTimeZone)
    }).ToList();
}
```